# Submitting Form on Enter Press

Tags: javascript, html

I know that this question has been asked before but I'm having particular trouble submitting my form when I press the enter key. I've tried multiple solutions but none have worked. When I try to press enter, the page refreshes and my typing is gone.
This is my HTML:

```
form class="nput">
    <h1 class= "header">Member Login</h1>
    <label class="text" for="pswd">Enter your password: </label>
    <input class="form" type="password" id="pswd">
    <input id="yeet" class="bttn" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="checkPswd();" />
</form>
```

And this is my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkPswd() {
        var confirmPassword = "password";
        var password = document.getElementById("pswd").value;
        if (password == confirmPassword) {
             window.location="members.html";
        }
        else{
            alert("Password incorrect. Please try again.");
        }
    }
    // Get the input field
    var input = document.getElementById("pswd");

    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        alert("hi there");
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("yeet").click();
  }
});
</script>
```

I cannot figure out this small issue and I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

EDIT: I just wanted to let everyone know that I do in fact know that there is little security that comes with this method but I mostly want the password for looks not function.

Comment: Is the missing `<` in front of the `<form>` a typo in your question, or in the actual source code you have?

Comment: Also, as a side note, it looks like you are trying to do authentication on the client side with javascript.  **That is easily broken**.  Any serious authentication implementation should be done on the server side.

Comment: Don't worry- I'm not putting anything serious on the other side of the password. I mainly want it for looks and a VERY light security since mostly older people will be using my website

Answer (score 1):

You got something backwards there - you *are* submitting the form with Enter. This is exactly the problem though, it seems as if you *don't* want to submit it, instead you want to run your client-side handler `checkPswd`. (You do know that everyone can read the correct password in their browser console though, right? So it's no protection.)

What you want to do is change the `onclick` on the button to an `onsubmit` on the form itself! Then your code will run no matter in what way (keyboard or mouse) the form is submitted.

You can delete the whole `keyup` stuff then.

(The reason your attempt to "click" the button in JavaScript wasn't working is because unlike jQuery's `click` method, the vanilla `click` will only execute the default action and not any attached `click` event handlers like yours. Also, it is kinda backwards because you should react on the common ground of both clicking the button and pressing Enter, which is *submitting the form*.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As I said above, I now have another issue... It works on the enter key press but when I put in the correct password, I have it log "hello" then run `window.location="members.html";` In the console, it logs hello for only a second then it disappears. Also, the page doesn't navigate to members.html

Comment: I guess you are not preventing the default submit action. Pass `event` as parameter to `checkPswd` and call `preventDefault` on it. (I.e., make it `onsubmit="checkPswd(event)"` and put `event.preventDefault()` into the `checkPswd` function)

Answer (score 1):

To echo a comment above - you want to use the `onsubmit` handler on the `<form>` element - this will allow users to submit the form both by clicking the `<button type="submit>` button, and by hitting the `enter` key in one of the forms `<input>` elements.

You can probably ditch the `input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {...}` altogether by just using the `obsubmit` handler.

You can learn more about the HTML `<form>` element's `onsubmit` behavior here:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onsubmit.asp

Comment: I now have another issue... It works on the enter key press but when I put in the correct password, I have it log "hello" then run window.location="members.html"; In the console, it logs hello for only a second then it disappears. Also, the page doesn't navigate to members.html

Comment: I don't know what you mean, there is no `hello` in your code

Answer (score 0):

No need to put handlers on button element. You should use either input type as submit or button type as submit. onsubmit handler can be given to form element where you can actually prevent default event and go ahead with password validation .

Hope this gives you an idea.

Answer (score -2):

If I were you, I would do two things:

1) I would check the Chrome debugger to see if there are any issues with your code

2) Instead of `input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {`, I would try `input.onkeyup = function(event) {` and see if that works.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `addEventListener` is preferred, why would you use `onkeyup`?